# No. of Cyclic prefix for 5G NR signal with 100Mhz bandwidth different subcarrier spacing?

Tags: ofdm, communication-standard

I want to generate a 100Mhz bandwidth 5G NR signal with different subcarrier spacing(15,30,60,120Khz) in matlab. What is the no. of CP to be added for 1st OFDM symbol and the other symbols and also which subcarrier spacing should I use to get bandwidth of 100Mhz. Is the sampling freq 153.6Mhz fixed for 5G NR signal?

Comment: Also what is difference between 5G NR and 5G TF

Comment: removed the unrelated tags.